# Why this gradient looks different in mozilla and chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Why this gradient looks different in mozilla and chrome?
In mozilla, everything looks as it should, but in chrome, for some reason, some areas are not displayed and blurring occurs.

```html
<svg width="5300" height="90" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id='gradientId' x1='0%' y1='0%' x2='100%' y2='0%'>
            <stop offset='0' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.002515382700630155' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.002515382700630155' stop-color='#913151'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.09527011978636715' stop-color='#913151'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.09527011978636715' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.7441916931233106' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.7441916931233106' stop-color='#913151'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.7885253132219171' stop-color='#913151'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.7885253132219171' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.8415160421151924' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.8415160421151924' stop-color='#913151'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.9308121279875629' stop-color='#913151'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.9308121279875629' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.9308226087488155' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.9308226087488155' stop-color='#988334'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.9471725963029115' stop-color='#988334'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.9471725963029115' stop-color='#988334'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.9999956330161448' stop-color='#988334'></stop>
            <stop offset='0.9999956330161448' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
            <stop offset='1' stop-color='#0064B4'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect rx="5" x="0" y="0" width="5300" height="90" fill="url(#gradientId)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: which one do you believe is correct?

Comment: mozzila is correct

Comment: Must be a bug in chrome `linearGradient` - wonder if it's been reported

Comment: I'd recall MDN docs says the decimals in SVG attributes should be limited to three, otherwise problems can be expected. I'll try to find the article.

Comment: even with 2 decimal places it's rubbish @Teemu :p - having less stops seems to make things work nicer

Comment: Definitely a Chrome bug. If you take out two of the stops, it works perfectly again.

Comment: I've reported the bug to Chrome. See [bug 1305530](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305530)